# Can you move your animations to an external file in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

The `@Component` annotation provides us with an `animations` property. This can be used to define a list of `triggers` each with a lot of `state` and `transition` properties.

When you add multiple animations to a component, this list can become pretty long. Also some animations would be really nice to use in other components as well. Having to put them directly in each component seems tedious and is repetitive - plus it violates the DRY principle.

You can define the template and styles properties on your component as well, but here you have the option of providing a `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` instead. I can't seem to find an `animationUrls` property - am i missing something - is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Sure you can. You can just declare the animation in a different file, then import it where you need it

animations.ts

```js
export const animation = trigger(...)
```

component.ts

```js
import { animation } from './animations'

@Component({
  animations: [ animation ]
})
```

Or if you want to make it configurable, you can export a function. For example, take a look at the [Fuel-UI Collapse](https://github.com/FuelInteractive/fuel-ui/blob/master/src/animations/Collapse/Collapse.ts). This is a reusable (and configurable) animation

collapse.ts

```js
export function Collapse(duration: number = 300) {
    return trigger('collapse', [
           ...
        ])
}
```

Then in your components, just use

```js
import { Collapse } from './collapse'

@Component({
  animations: [ Collapse(300) ],
  template: `
    <div @collapse="collapsed ? 'true' : 'false'">
    </div>
  `
})
class MyComponent {}
```

Comment: Nice touch with the variable passed through a function :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!You did a great job!

Comment: and outside of the template layout? what if you have an html file like in angular cli?

Answer (score 4):

Sure that's possible. You can make for instance an `animations.ts` and let it export all kind of animation constants:

```js
export const PRETTY_ANIMATION = trigger('heroState', [
  state('inactive', style({
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    transform: 'scale(1)'
  })),
  state('active',   style({
    backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
    transform: 'scale(1.1)'
  })),
  transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
  transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
])
```

and in your component you can import this animation using the `import` statement:

```js
import {PRETTY_ANIMATION} from 'animations';
```

and apply it to your component:

```js
@Component({
    selector : `...`
    animations : [PRETTY_ANIMATION]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You certainly and the gentlemen has done so in some of his github repo examples. Take the following:

route_animations.ts

```js
import {
    trigger,
    animate,
    style,
    transition
} from '@angular/core';

var startingStyles = (styles) => {
    styles['position'] = 'fixed';
    styles['top'] = 0;
    styles['left'] = 0;
    styles['right'] = 0;
    styles['height'] = '100%';
    return styles;
}

export default function(name) {
    return trigger(name, [
        transition('void => *', [
            style(startingStyles({
                transform: 'translateX(100%)'
            })),
            animate('0.5s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)'}))
        ]),
        transition('* => void', [
            style(startingStyles({
                transform: 'translateX(0%)'
            })),
            animate('0.5s ease-in', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}))
        ])
    ]);
}
```

Which is then imported into a component like the following:

```js
import {default as routerAnimations} from '../route_animations';
```

And then called like this under the animation Param when initialising the component:

```js
animations: [routerAnimations('route')],
```

Take a look at this yourself to get a better idea but I hope this helps. https://github.com/matsko/ng2eu-2016-code/blob/master

Kudos to matsko.

Comment: the link provided it no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example fade in animation in Angular 4 I use for animating routes

```js
// import the required animation functions from the angular animations module
import { trigger, state, animate, transition, style } from '@angular/animations';
 
export const fadeInAnimation =
    // trigger name for attaching this animation to an element using the [@triggerName] syntax
    trigger('fadeInAnimation', [
 
        // route 'enter' transition
        transition(':enter', [
 
            // css styles at start of transition
            style({ opacity: 0 }),
 
            // animation and styles at end of transition
            animate('.3s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
        ]),
    ]);
```

And a component with the transition attached

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 
// import fade in animation
import { fadeInAnimation } from '../_animations/index';
 
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
 
    // make fade in animation available to this component
    animations: [fadeInAnimation],
 
    // attach the fade in animation to the host (root) element of this component
    host: { '[@fadeInAnimation]': '' }
})
 
export class HomeComponent {
}
```

More details and a live demo at [this post](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/04/19/angular-2-4-router-animation-tutorial-example)

Comment: thanks for specifying how to do this when not coding in the (unsustainable) template format. :)