# Hook to animation callback without trigger in Angular 2

Tags: css, angular, animation

I have a component called header.component and I need to call a method when a css animation finishes.

I have seen a lot of examples where you can use the following syntax

```
  <div class="header-div" (@anim.done)="onAnimationFinish($event)"></div>
```

to call method onAnimationFinish (defined in the header.component.ts file). However, this will only work if you have defined
a trigger in the .ts file.

I would like to keep my animations and transitions defined in the .css file so my question is:

is there any way to define an animation trigger that will be linked to a @keyframe animation in the header.component.css file or is it 100% compulsory
that I define my css animations with triggers when using Angular 2?

My css:

```
@keyframes anim {
0% { position:relative; width: 50px; left: 0px; }
50% { position:relative; width: 100px; left: -25px; }
100% { position:relative; width: 50px; left: 0px; } 
}
```

The .ts file only contains the function that should be called when animation 'anim' finishes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `animationend` event. This has poor browser compatibility though.

Another option would be, because you would like to keep your animations separate is to define these in a separate typescript file, and import them where you need them.

Check here to see how to:
[Can you move your animations to an external file in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40375258/can-you-move-your-animations-to-an-external-file-in-angular2/40375542#40375542)

Comment: Hi Pierre. I'm not really getting the hang of animation handling in Angular 2 but I see triggers are probably the way to go. As you can see, my animation example is quite simple but I'm struggling to define it as a trigger since it's expecting way more info than I wrote in the animation definition in the css file. Could you provide an example of how would @Component look like defining my css animation as a trigger? I will then import a component storing all of my animations as suggested :)

Comment: I'm sorry. I have not yet used the animations from angular2 :) [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html) but this is a good start

Answer (score 0):

You can use the animationend event and wrap it up into a own attribute directive using anuglar `HostListener`. It would be used like that:

```
<div class="header-div" [myAnimationEnd]="onAnimationFinish($event)"</div>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_animationend.asp

If this suits your need you need more detail on that approach i can provide you a example implementation later.

Comment: Hi Quali, thanks for your answer. However, I would like to avoid using animationend event.