# Angular styles styleUrl templates templateUrl

Tags: angular, animation

I am working with Angular and trying to tidy up my code.
For the templates there is templateURL, the same with styles.
But, what about Animations is there a way to put in a different file?

```
selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
        trigger('blasted', [
    state('up', style({
      //transform: 'rotate(-90deg)',
      background: "grey",
      opacity:0.4,
      transform: 'rotate(-2deg)',
    })),
    state('blow', style({.......................................
```

I needed an animationUrl

Comment: check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40375258/can-you-move-your-animations-to-an-external-file-in-angular2), Cheers!!

Comment: This title makes no sense.