# Exported Animation is Undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-animations

I am using a **fade in** animation in my angular component. If I define the animation inside the component decorator under **`animations: []`**, it works fine. However, I want to reuse the animation in different component therefore I have moved it to another file and exporting it from there. When I use this animation, it give my **`undefined`** error. I analyzed it and the **`fadeInAnimation`** is undefined. Here is my code:

**fade-in.animation.ts**

```
import { trigger, animate, transition, style } from '@angular/animations';
export const fadeInAnimation = trigger('fadeInAnimation', [
    transition(':enter', [
        // styles at start of transition
        style({ opacity: 0 }),

        // animation and styles at end of transition
        animate('.3s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
    ]),
]);
```

I am importing this animation in my component like this:

```
import { fadeInAnimation } from './animations/fade-in.animation';
// Other imports
@Component({
    selector: 'app-some-component',
    templateUrl: './some.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./some.component.scss'],
    animations: [ fadeInAnimation ]
})
```

.. and using it in my component template like this:

```
<div [@fadeInAnimation]>Some content</div>
```

I am unable to understand why this animation works when I define it inside the component and doesn't work when I export the same from another file. **What am I missing?**

---

Someone set this as a duplicate of [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40375258/can-you-move-your-animations-to-an-external-file-in-angular2). I have done everything which is given in that other answer and the issue is still unresolved. The other question is related to creating separate animation files, which I am already doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you move your animations to an external file in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40375258/can-you-move-your-animations-to-an-external-file-in-angular2)

Comment: @TiagoMachado these are two different question.